# Observing a hard-disk write in kernel space (with drivers/modules)

Tags: linux-kernel, debugging, trace

Apologies in advance if this post is a bit dense/messy, but I'm having a hard time formulating it better... Basically, I would like to study what happens upon a hard disk write, and I'd like to know:

- Is my understanding below correct - and if not, where am I going wrong?
- Is there a better tool to "capture" log data, about all aspects happening on the PC, during a disk write?

In more detail - first, the OS I'm using is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mypc 2.6.38-16-generic #67-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 6 18:00:43 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

So, I have the following simple (e.g. the usual checks for failure of operations are skipped) user-space C program, `wtest.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>  // O_CREAT, O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR

int main(void) {
  char filename[] = "/tmp/wtest.txt";
  char buffer[] = "abcd";
  int fd;
  mode_t perms = S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR|S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP|S_IROTH|S_IWOTH;

  fd = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT, perms);
  write(fd,buffer,4);
  close(fd);

  return 0;
}
```

I build this with `gcc -g -O0 -o wtest wtest.c`. Now, since I'm trying to write to `/tmp`, I note that it is a directory under the root `/` - so I check `mount`:

```
$ mount
/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
...
/dev/sda6 on /media/disk1 type ext4 (rw,uhelper=hal,commit=0)
/dev/sda7 on /media/disk2 type ext3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,commit=0,commit=0,commit=0,commit=0,commit=0,commit=0)
...
```

So, my root filesystem `/` is one partition of the `/dev/sda` device (and I'm using other partitions as "standalone" disks/mounts, too). To find the driver for this device, I use `hwinfo`:

```
$ hwinfo --disk
...
19: IDE 00.0: 10600 Disk
...
  SysFS ID: /class/block/sda
  SysFS BusID: 0:0:0:0
...
  Hardware Class: disk
  Model: "FUJITSU MHY225RB"
...
  Driver: "ata_piix", "sd"
  Driver Modules: "ata_piix"
  Device File: /dev/sda
...
  Device Number: block 8:0-8:15
...
```

So, the `/dev/sda` hard disk is apparently handled by `ata_piix` (and `sd`) driver.

```
$ grep 'ata_piix\| sd' <(gunzip </var/log/syslog.2.gz)
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    1.963846] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: version 2.13
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    1.963901] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: PCI INT B -> GSI 19 (level, low) -> IRQ 19
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    1.963912] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: MAP [ P0 P2 P1 P3 ]
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    2.116038] ata_piix 0000:00:1f.2: setting latency timer to 64
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    2.116817] scsi0 : ata_piix
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    2.117068] scsi1 : ata_piix
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    2.529065] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 488397168 512-byte logical blocks: (250 GB/232 GiB)
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    2.529104] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    2.529309] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    2.529319] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    2.529423] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    2.674783]  sda: sda1 sda2 < sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8 sda9 sda10 >
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    2.676075] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    4.145312] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Jan 20 09:28:31 mypc kernel: [    4.150596] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I have to pull from older syslog as I suspend a lot, but the above seems like the proper snippet from the syslog at boot time, where the `ata_piix` (and `sd`) driver kicks in for the first time.

My first point of confusion is that I cannot otherwise observe the `ata_piix` or `sd` drivers:

```
$ lsmod | grep 'ata_piix\| sd'
$
$ modinfo sd
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module sd
$ modinfo ata_piix
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ata_piix
```

So my first question is - why cannot I observe the `ata_piix` module here, only in boot-time logs? Is it because `ata_piix` (and `sd`) are built as built-in drivers in the (monolithic) kernel, as opposed to being built as (loadable) `.ko` kernel modules?

Right - so now, I'm trying to observe what happens upon running the program with `ftrace` Linux built-in function tracer.

```
sudo bash -c '
KDBGPATH="/sys/kernel/debug/tracing"
echo function_graph > $KDBGPATH/current_tracer
echo funcgraph-abstime > $KDBGPATH/trace_options
echo funcgraph-proc > $KDBGPATH/trace_options
echo 0 > $KDBGPATH/tracing_on
echo > $KDBGPATH/trace
echo 1 > $KDBGPATH/tracing_on ; ./wtest ; echo 0 > $KDBGPATH/tracing_on
cat $KDBGPATH/trace > wtest.ftrace
'
```

... and here is a snippet of the `ftrace` log concerning the `write`:

```
 4604.352690 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |  sys_write() {
 4604.352690 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.750 us    |    fget_light();
 4604.352692 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |    vfs_write() {
 4604.352693 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |      rw_verify_area() {
 4604.352693 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |        security_file_permission() {
 4604.352694 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |          apparmor_file_permission() {
 4604.352695 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.811 us    |            common_file_perm();
 4604.352696 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   2.198 us    |          }
 4604.352697 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   3.573 us    |        }
 4604.352697 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   4.979 us    |      }
 4604.352698 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |      do_sync_write() {
 4604.352699 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |        ext4_file_write() {
 4604.352700 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |          generic_file_aio_write() {
 4604.352701 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |            mutex_lock() {
 4604.352701 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.666 us    |              _cond_resched();
 4604.352703 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   1.994 us    |            }
 4604.352704 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |            __generic_file_aio_write() {
...
 4604.352728 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |              file_update_time() {
...
 4604.352732 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.756 us    |                mnt_want_write_file();
 4604.352734 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                __mark_inode_dirty() {
...
 4604.352750 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                    ext4_mark_inode_dirty() {
 4604.352750 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.679 us    |                      _cond_resched();
 4604.352752 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                      ext4_reserve_inode_write() {
...
 4604.352777 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                        __ext4_journal_get_write_access() {
...
 4604.352795 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                      ext4_mark_iloc_dirty() {
...
 4604.352806 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                    __ext4_journal_stop() {
...
 4604.352821 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.684 us    |                mnt_drop_write();
 4604.352822 |   0)  wtest-31632   | + 93.541 us   |              }
 4604.352823 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |              generic_file_buffered_write() {
 4604.352824 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.654 us    |                iov_iter_advance();
 4604.352825 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                generic_perform_write() {
 4604.352826 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.709 us    |                  iov_iter_fault_in_readable();
 4604.352828 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                  ext4_da_write_begin() {
 4604.352829 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                    ext4_journal_start_sb() {
...
 4604.352847 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   1.453 us    |                    __block_write_begin();
 4604.352849 |   0)  wtest-31632   | + 21.128 us   |                  }
 4604.352849 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                  iov_iter_copy_from_user_atomic() {
 4604.352850 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                    __kmap_atomic() {
...
 4604.352863 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.672 us    |                  mark_page_accessed();
 4604.352864 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                  ext4_da_write_end() {
 4604.352865 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                    generic_write_end() {
 4604.352866 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                      block_write_end() {
...
 4604.352893 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |                    __ext4_journal_stop() {
...
 4604.352909 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.655 us    |            mutex_unlock();
 4604.352911 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.727 us    |            generic_write_sync();
 4604.352912 |   0)  wtest-31632   | ! 212.259 us  |          }
 4604.352913 |   0)  wtest-31632   | ! 213.845 us  |        }
 4604.352914 |   0)  wtest-31632   | ! 215.286 us  |      }
 4604.352914 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.685 us    |      __fsnotify_parent();
 4604.352916 |   0)  wtest-31632   |               |      fsnotify() {
 4604.352916 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.907 us    |        __srcu_read_lock();
 4604.352918 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   0.685 us    |        __srcu_read_unlock();
 4604.352920 |   0)  wtest-31632   |   3.958 us    |      }
 4604.352920 |   0)  wtest-31632   | ! 228.409 us  |    }
 4604.352921 |   0)  wtest-31632   | ! 231.334 us  |  }
```

This is my second point of confusion - I can observe the user-space `write()` resulted with a kernel-space `sys_write()`, as expected; and within the `sys_write()`, I observe security-related functions (e.g. `apparmor_file_permission()`), "generic" write functions (e.g. `generic_file_aio_write()`), `ext4` filesystem related functions (e.g. `ext4_journal_start_sb()`) - but I do *not* observe anything related to `ata_piix` (or `sd`) drivers ?!

The page [Tracing and Profiling - Yocto Project](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Tracing_and_Profiling) suggests using the `blk` tracer in `ftrace` to get more information about block device operation, but it reports nothing for me with this example. Also, [Linux Filesystem Drivers - Annon Inglorion (tutorfs)](http://inglorion.net/documents/tutorials/tutorfs/) suggests that filesystems are (can?) also (be) implemented as kernel modules/drivers, and I'm guessing that is the case for `ext4` as well.

Finally, I could have sworn that I have earlier observed the driver name in square brackets next to the function shown by the `function_graph` tracer, but I guess I had mixed things up - it can probably appear like that in stack (back)traces, but not in the function graph. Furthermore, I can inspect `/proc/kallsyms`:

```
$ grep 'piix\| sd\|psmouse' /proc/kallsyms
...
00000000 d sd_ctl_dir
00000000 d sd_ctl_root
00000000 d sdev_class
00000000 d sdev_attr_queue_depth_rw
00000000 d sdev_attr_queue_ramp_up_period
00000000 d sdev_attr_queue_type_rw
00000000 d sd_disk_class
...
00000000 t piix_init_sata_map
00000000 t piix_init_sidpr
00000000 t piix_init_one
00000000 t pci_fixup_piix4_acpi
...
00000000 t psmouse_show_int_attr        [psmouse]
00000000 t psmouse_protocol_by_type     [psmouse]
00000000 r psmouse_protocols    [psmouse]
00000000 t psmouse_get_maxproto [psmouse]
...
```

... and checking with source [Linux/drivers/ata/ata_piix.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/ata/ata_piix.c?v=2.6.38), confirm that e.g. `piix_init_sata_map` is indeed a function in `ata_piix`. Which should probably tell me that: modules that are compiled in the kernel (so they become a part of the monolithic kernel) "lose" the information about which module they come from; however, the loadable modules which are built as separate `.ko` kernel objects, preserve that information (e.g. `[psmouse]` shown above in square brackets). Thus, also `ftrace` could only show "originating module" information, only for those functions coming from loadable kernel modules. Is this correct?

The above taken into consideration, this is the understanding that I have of the process currently:

- At boot time, the `ata_piix` driver establishes a DMA (?) memory mapping between `/dev/sda` and the hard disk

  - because of this, all future accesses to `/dev/sda` via `ata_piix` will be transparent to the kernel (that is, not traceable) - since all the kernel would see, are just reads/writes to memory locations (not necessarily calls to specific traceable kernel functions), which are not reported by `function_graph` tracer
- At boot time, the `sd` driver will furthermore "parse" the partitions of `/dev/sda`, make them available, and possibly handle the memory mappings between partitions <-> disk device

  - again, this should make the access operations via `sd` transparent to the kernel
- Since both `ata_piix` and `sd` are compiled in-kernel, even if some of their functions do end up being captured by `ftrace`, we cannot get an information of which module those functions would come from (apart from "manual" correlation with source files)
- Later on, `mount` establishes a relationship/binding between a partition, and the corresponding *filesystem* driver (in this case `ext4`)

  - from this point on, all of the accesses to the mounted filesystem would be handled by `ext4` functions - which are traceable by the kernel; but as `ext4` is compiled in-kernel, the tracer cannot give us the originating module information
- So, the observed "generic" writes, called via `ext4` functions, would ultimately access memory locations, whose mapping is established by `ata_piix` - but other than that, `ata_piix` doesn't interfere directly with data transfers (it being probably handled by DMA (outside of the processor(s), and thus transparent to it).

Is this understanding correct?

Some related subquestions:

- In my setup above, I can identify a PCI device driver (`ata_piix`) and a filesystem driver (`ext4`); but are there character or block drivers used somewhere on the "write" execution path, and if so, which are they?
- Which of those drivers would handle caching (so unnecessary disk operations are skipped or optimized?)
- I know from before that `/dev/shm` is a filesystem in RAM; `mount | grep shm` for me reports: `none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)`. Does that mean that - in contrast to `/dev/sda` - the `shm` filesystem simply lacks the (DMA) mapping from "its own" adrresses to bus addresses towards a device; and thus all accesses via the `tmpfs` filesystem driver end up in actual RAM?

Comment: Hi sdaau. This are a good questions, but the length of this post is excessive, and there are several questions in there. It is commendable that you are trying to understand things, rather than just asking help desk questions, which is what we mostly get here. Each of these questions would merit a long answer by themselves. I recommend at least breaking down your post into clearly defined pieces, and putting each piece into a separate question, thus creating a series of questions.

Comment: Then you can post these questions together or sequentially. It is Ok, I think, if you reference another question (or questions) within a question.

Comment: If you want tips on cleaning up your question, I suggest you hop into the chatroom and talk to the people there. We've already been talking about it here. :-)

Comment: Many thanks for the comment, @FaheemMitha - I also had similar doubts, but I wasn't really sure how to cut up the questions - and wasn't aware until now I can use chat for it (and I wasn't keen on using meta for asking about that kind of advice); will definitely give chat a try next time. Thankfully, this time it worked out with a very acceptable answer ... Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau, did you figure out how to monitor the disk access ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've asked way too much in one question—well, technically not, as I guess "is this understanding correct" can be answered quickly: no. But that's not a useful answer.

First, you're right about `ata_piix` and `sd_mod` apparently being compiled-in to your kernel. That's a choice you make configuring the kernel—you can omit it, include it, or include it as a module. (Same with ext4).

Second, you have assumed writes to be far simpler than they actually are. The basic outline of how a write works is that the filesystem code puts the data to be written in memory, as part of the buffer-cache, and marks it as needs-to-be-written ("dirty"). (Unless there is already too much of that in RAM, in which case it actually is forced to do the write...)

Later, various things (such as the `bdflush` kernel thread) actually flush the dirty pages to disk. This is when you'd see calls through sd, scsi, libata, ata_piix, io schedulers, PCI, etc. While there is very likely DMA involved in that write-out, it's of the data to be transferred, and maybe the command. But disk writes, at least in SATA, are handled by sending commands which basically mean "write sector X with data Y". But it's definitely not handled by memory-mapping the entire disk (consider: you can use disks far larger than 4GiB on 32-bit machines).

Caching is handled by the memory management subsystem (not a driver), in conjunction with the filesystem, block layer, etc.

`tmpfs` is special, it is basically *entirely* cache. Its just special cache that is never discarded or written back (though it can be swapped out). You can find the code in [`mm/shmem.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/shmem.c) and several other places (try `ack-grep --cc CONFIG_TMPFS` to find them).

Basically, writing to disk goes through a good portion of the kernel's subsystems; networking is the only major one I can think of that isn't involved in your example. Properly explaining it requires a book-length effort; I recommend looking for one.

Comment: Hi @derobert - many, many thanks for your answer; it contains the exact kind of information I was missing! I originally started with looking for a simple illustration of user vs. kernel space, but I realized soon a hard-disk write isn't exactly something I understand fully, and isn't that trivial - thanks for confirming it is actually a book-length effort! Cheers!

Comment: A small note: some of the explanation in this answer (e.g. dirty pages flushing) is observable, if in the `sudo bash...` script in the OP: ftrace memory is increased (`echo 8192 > $KDBGPATH/buffer_size_kb`); and `sync ;` is added after the `./wtest ;` call. Then I can see `flush-8`, `kworker` (under `kthreadd` in `ps axf`), and `sync` itself, as processes in `ftrace` calling functions like e.g. `ata_bmdma_setup()` (which is part of `libata`, which `ata_piix` builds on), or `get_nr_dirty_inodes()`.

Answer (score 4):

> So my first question is - why cannot I observe the ata_piix module
>   here, only in boot-time logs? Is it because ata_piix (and sd) are
>   built as built-in drivers in the (monolithic) kernel, as opposed to
>   being built as (loadable) .ko kernel modules?

You don't have to guess what your configuration is. On my machine I have

```
$ uname -a
Linux orwell 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The config file is for this kernel is located at `/boot/config-3.2.0-4-amd64`.

You asked about `ata_piix`. Searching the above `.config` file, we see
`CONFIG_ATA_PIIX=m`. we can confirm this by doing

```
dlocate ata_piix.ko
```

alternatively

```
dpkg -S ata_piix.ko

linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64: /lib/modules/3.2.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/ata/ata_piix.ko
```

So at least in my kernel, it is a module.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @FaheemMitha - while I've heard of (and used) the config file before, for some reason I've completely forgotten about it in this example; nicely spotted! `:)` On my system, `grep ATA_PIIX /boot/config-2.6.38-16-generic` says `CONFIG_ATA_PIIX=y`, which should probably mean on this kernel, `ata_piix` is build "in-kernel", and not as a module. Cheers!